# Probability using combinatorics problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The problem is simple: "Find the probability of getting no aces with four dice".

Now, i'm supposed to solve this using combinatorics.

So, I see two ways of doing this.

First: considering my sample space to be ordered sequences of lenght 4, each position taking 6 possible values (with repetition). Which would be the same as having to assign 4 **distinguishable** balls to 6 cells. Which gives me $6^4$ possible cases. "Affirmative" cases would then be given in the same way by $5^4$. So, probability would be $(5/6)^4$. So far, so good.

The question arises with the second possible method that I thought of. Going back to the balls and cells example, ¿Why should I treat the balls as distinguishable from each other? I mean, the problem doesn't state anything about the four dice being numbered or ordered in any way. I figure that I should consider <2,5,6,3> and <3,5,6,2> above to be the same sample point.

So, if we consider the possible distributions of 4 **indistinguishable** balls in 6 cells (again, with repetition), we'd have ${(6-1)+4 \choose 4}$ possible cases, of which ${(5-1)+4 \choose 4}$ are the affirmative ones (the ways of assigning 4 indistinguishable balls in only 5 cells).

Problem is, I get two different results using the two methods: 0,48... for the first, and 0,55... for the second. And since the first amounts to using the multiplication rule, I know it to be right. So, finally, the question is: What's wrong with using the second method? Why doesn't it yield the same result?

EDIT: I can't vote up answers, but I wanted to thank all of you guys, I perfectly understand my mistake now!

Comment: In the second way, for the calculation you are implicitly assuming that the $\binom{9}{4}$ "patterns" are equally likely. They are not. Just as when tossing two coins, double head, mixed, and double tail are not equally likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I figure that I should consider <2,5,6,3> and <3,5,6,2> above to be the same sample point.

There are 24 permutations of there four symbols (2,3,5,6), which you would consider to be all the same sample point.  The probability that sample point is thus $24 / 6^4$.

You would also consider <2,2,2,3>, <2,2,3,2>, et cetera to be the same sample point.  But there are just 4 permutations of these symbols.  The probability of this point would then be $4/6^4$.

So modelling the dice as indistinguishable leads to a set of sample points which are not equally probable.

Thus, although *in practice* you do not keep track of the distinction of the dice after they've been rolled, by *modelling* the dice as distinguishable you obtain sets of sample points which are equally probable.

---

Consider the case of tossing just two coins.  If you model the coins as distinquishable you obtain the result set: $\{ (H,H), (H,T), (T,H), (T,T)\}$, each with a probability of $1/4$.

If you model the coins as interchangeable you obtain $\{ ($Two Heads$), ($One of Each$), ($Two Tails$)\}$.  But each outcome does *not* have an equal probability of occurring because, although you may not be able to tell the coins apart nor care about the order in which they land, they are actually different objects.

---

In short, measuring probability of an outcome is not just a matter of counting distinct results.  You also have to consider the probability *weight* of each outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Because in the second method, some indistinguishable combinations occur more than others.  Let's reduce it to two dice to simplify.  And you're looking for the probability of rolling a $(1,1)$ or a "two".  You know it is $\frac{1}{36}$ using the correct method, but there are also only 11 possible outcomes $2 \text{ thru }12$ which would make the answer $\frac{1}{11}$ using your second method.

The reason this isn't correct is that some outcomes are much more likely to occur.  For example, a seven is rolled 6 times as often as a two.